# Intersection Observer: padding changes 'boundaries' of root element?

Tags: html, intersection-observer

When I run the example (in full page view) in Chrome (98) (or Safari 15.3) the first element directly vanishes when scrolling just a little bit, so kind of 'when leaving the non-padding or entering the padding-area'
The options define a `rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px'` which I thought refer to the root elements border. That's how it behaves in  Firefox(97). The inner element is only hidden when it reaches the top.

Is there a way to define the wrapper borders as boundary and not the 'inner padding-border'?

```js
        const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper')
        const firstElem = document.querySelector('#first-elem')
        const options = {
            root: wrapper,
            rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px',
            threshold: 1
        }
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleFade, options);
        observer.observe(firstElem)

        function handleFade(entries) {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                let target = entry.target
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    target.classList.remove('fade-out')
                } else {
                    target.classList.add('fade-out')
                }
            })
        }
```

```css
body {
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #wrapper {
        height: 100vh;
        padding-top: 10rem;
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px solid darkmagenta;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .elem {
        border: 3px solid teal;
        padding: 0 2rem;
        height: 20rem;
    }
.fade-out {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="elem" id="first-elem">first watched element</div>
    <div class="elem">element</div>
    <div class="elem">element</div>
    <div class="elem">element</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. This might be a bit confusing but it seems to be the expected behavior according to the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/#:%7E:text=an%20overflow%20clip%2C-,it%E2%80%99s%20the%20element%E2%80%99s%20content%20area.,-Otherwise%2C).

When you set a `root` for an `IntersectionObserver` instance, the so-called [intersection rectangle](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/#intersectionobserver-root-intersection-rectangle) — the area that the intersection is checked against — will be the [content area](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box/#content-area) of the root element.

The content area refers to the innermost area of an element, which excludes all the paddings:

[image]

As for the solution to this problem, you could simply have an extra wrapper element that you set the paddings on, and you remove any paddings from the `root` element:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
const firstElem = document.querySelector('#first-elem');

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries[0].target.classList.toggle('fade-out', !entries[0].isIntersecting)
}, {
    root: wrapper,
    threshold: 1,
});
  
observer.observe(firstElem)
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid darkmagenta;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 10rem;
}

.elem {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.fade-out {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="elem" id="first-elem">first watched element</div>
    <div class="elem">element</div>
    <div class="elem">element</div>
    <div class="elem">element</div> 
    <div class="elem">element</div> 
    <div class="elem">element</div> 
    <div class="elem">element</div> 
    <div class="elem">element</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Although your example is a bit strange, in the sense that I'm not sure what you were wanting to do, but regardless, any time you want to neutralize the effect of the paddings on the `root` but still have paddings around your content, the solution is to declare the paddings on an extra wrapper element.

Comment: Thanks for the specs! So if the root settings refer to the content area - which excludes the padding - the behaviour in firefox is incorrect. Your workaround seems plausible, but when I run the snippet in 'full page' mode, the first element is already invisible and when scrolling down becomes visible when leaving the wrapper. I think that's due to the condition inside toggle, which should be the opposite `!entry.isIntersecting`

Comment: @Corrl Oh yeah, it seems like Chrome and Firefox disagree in this regard. I wasn't aware of this. It's strange, I'm not sure if there's already a bug report or something like that for either browser. But still, the no-padding workaround would neutralize the inconsistency and make sure that your site functions identically in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Corrl As per the snippet, you're right, the condition should be reversed, I also modified the styles a little bit to make the functionality more clear. You can check it out again and let me know if it makes sense now. What's happening is that as soon as a single pixel of the first element is out of the viewport, the whole element fades out, and the padding isn't causing any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to mention that on the **18/10/23** the specs have been updated:
[https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/pull/517/files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci886.png)

The [intersection area](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/#intersectionobserver-root-intersection-rectangle) is now the padding-area rather than the content-area.

That means that if you have some paddings in the root element and you want the interesctionObserver to take them into account then you need to set the [rootMargin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/rootMargin) prop accordingly.

The combination of paddings and rootMargin is useful when you want to implement things like the following carousel, where the "active" area of a scrollable element is a fraction of its width:

[carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ebH7.png)

This also means that Blink and Gecko (Chrome, Firefox) now adhere to the specs while Webkit (Safari) has an [open bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263316)

Answer (score 0):

Given that the scrolled `wrapper` element takes up the full height of the page, a different solution would be to simply remove `root: wrapper` from the options, so the elements position is watched in relation to the viewport

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper')
        const firstElem = document.querySelector('#first-elem')
        const options = {
            rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px',
            threshold: 1
        }
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleFade, options);
        observer.observe(firstElem)

        function handleFade(entries) {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                let target = entry.target
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    target.classList.remove('fade-out')
                } else {
                    target.classList.add('fade-out')
                }
            })
        }
```

```css
body {
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #wrapper {
        height: 100vh;
        padding-top: 10rem;
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px solid darkmagenta;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .elem {
        border: 3px solid teal;
        padding: 0 2rem;
        height: 20rem;
    }
.fade-out {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="elem" id="first-elem">first watched element</div>
    <div class="elem">element</div>
    <div class="elem">element</div>
    <div class="elem">element</div> 
</div>
```